# What does "scale" mean in this code about SIR model?

Tags: calculus

[This code](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2020/02/11/the-kermack-mckendrick-sir-disease-model-using-c/kermack-mckendrick_demo/) is in `C#`, and I don't understand the purpose of the `scale` variable.

```
S = S + dS * scale
I = I + dI * scale
R = R + dR * scale
t = t + dt * scale
```

Is the purpose of this `scale`, to scale the graph horizontally? I think it should be horizontal, but I don't quite get it. Also, how can we do this in general, for instance, the function $f(x) = x^{2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `dt` equals 1, `scale` is just the time step in [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method).

It would perhaps have been clearer to get rid of the `scale` variable, rename `dS` to `dS_dt` (for $dS/dt$) and similarly for `dI` and `dR`, define `dt` to be equal to whatever `scale` was (0.1 in this case), and write the code as

```
S = S + dS_dt * dt
I = I + dI_dt * dt
R = R + dR_dt * dt
t = t + dt
```

Your question about $f(x)=x^2$ doesn't really make sense in this context. (Not to me, at least.)